# Dont kown how to fetch database?

Tags: c, sqlite, gtk, codeblocks

I'm complete beginner with sqlite and gtk. I'm making my 1st project in code::blocks.
I have a problem in fetching the database my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include "sqlite3.c"
#include <sqlite3.h>
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
 int i;
 fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", (const char*)data);
 for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
  printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
}
printf("\n");
return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 sqlite3 *db;
 char *zErrMsg = 0;
 int rc;
 char *sql;
 const char* data = "Callback function called";

 /* Open database */
 rc = sqlite3_open("sign_in.db", &db);
 if( rc ){
  fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
  exit(0);
  }else{
  fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
  }


 GtkWidget *window;
 GtkWidget *table;
 GdkColor color;


 GtkWidget *label1;
 GtkWidget *label2;
 GtkWidget *label3;

 GtkWidget *entry1;
 GtkWidget *entry2;

 GtkWidget *button1;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

 window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
 gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
 gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "LOG IN");
  gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 30);
 gtk_widget_modify_bg(window, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);


 table = gtk_table_new(3, 2, FALSE);
 gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), table);

 label1 = gtk_label_new("----------------------------------   LOGIN AND ENJOY OUR  FACILITY   -----------------------------------");
 label2 = gtk_label_new("USERNAME :");
 label3= gtk_label_new("PASSWORD :");


 button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label("LOG IN");

 gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
   GTK_FILL |GTK_EXPAND | GTK_SHRINK, GTK_FILL |GTK_EXPAND | GTK_SHRINK, 5, 5);
 gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label2, 0, 1, 1, 2,
   GTK_FILL | GTK_EXPAND |GTK_SHRINK, GTK_FILL | GTK_EXPAND |GTK_SHRINK, 5, 5);
 gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label3, 0, 1, 2, 3,
  GTK_FILL | GTK_EXPAND |GTK_SHRINK, GTK_FILL | GTK_EXPAND |GTK_SHRINK, 5, 5);

 entry1 = gtk_entry_new();
 entry2 = gtk_entry_new();

 gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), entry1, 1, 2, 1, 2,
  GTK_FILL |GTK_EXPAND | GTK_SHRINK, GTK_FILL |GTK_EXPAND | GTK_SHRINK, 5, 5);
 gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), entry2, 1, 2, 2, 3,
  GTK_FILL |GTK_EXPAND | GTK_SHRINK, GTK_FILL |GTK_EXPAND | GTK_SHRINK, 5, 5);
 gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), button1, 1, 2, 3, 4,
  GTK_FILL |GTK_EXPAND | GTK_SHRINK, GTK_FILL |GTK_EXPAND | GTK_SHRINK, 5, 5);
  gtk_widget_show(table);

  gtk_widget_show(label1);
   gtk_widget_show(label2);
   gtk_widget_show(label3);
     gtk_widget_show(entry1);
   gtk_widget_show(entry2);
   gtk_widget_show(button1);

   gtk_widget_show(window);


   /* Create SQL statement */
   sql="SELECT * from user where username='char *entry1' and password='char *entry2 '";
   if(sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg))
  {
   int count=0;
   while(sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg)+1)
   {
       count++;
   }
   if(count==1)
    fprintf(stdout, "username and password is correct\n");
          if(count>1)
    fprintf(stdout, "Dulitcate user\n");
           if(count<1)
    fprintf(stdout, "username and password is not correct\n");

   }
     /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
  if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
   fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
  sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
  }else{
  fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
  }
 sqlite3_close(db);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button1), "clicked",
  G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), G_OBJECT(window));


  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy",
  G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
```

I'm facing problem in these line (from above code):

1. In SELECT statement( i know its totally wrong ,please correct it).
2. In sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg)++ (in while loop)

   ```
   /* Create SQL statement */
   sql="SELECT * from user where username='char *entry1' and password='char *entry2 '";
    if(sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg))
    {
    int count=0;
    while(sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg)++)
    {
      count++;
    }
    if(count==1)
    fprintf(stdout, "username and password is correct\n");
         if(count>1)
    fprintf(stdout, "Dulitcate user\n");
          if(count<1)
    fprintf(stdout, "username and password is not correct\n");

    }
    /* Execute SQL statement */
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
    if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }else{
    fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
   ```

   please help me.i'really need someone help.thanx in advance

Comment: 1.) use a separator for the select statement where you need to give input from the code.. like string a="Select"+entry1+..

And what is the error on the exec line?

Comment: Thanx but It give error::: 
     "invalid operands to binary +(have 'char  * ' and 'struct GtkWidget') "

Comment: and for exec it don't take "++" operand..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlite3_exec` is not suitable if you want to handle the returned data at the place where you are querying it, and has some other disadvantages.

For a query, you should always use [sqlite3_prepare_v2](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html), and then call [sqlite3_step](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) in a loop.
To get variable values into the statement, use parameter markers (`?`) and the [sqlite3_bind*](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) functions.
To read returned values, use the [sqlite3_column_*](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) functions (but in this case, you don't actually want to read any values).

```
char *user = "Supu";
char *password = "secret";
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
const char *sql = "SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: %s, %s\n", sql, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
} else {
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, user, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, password, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        printf("returned row: user = %s, password = %s\n",
               sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0),
               sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1));
        count++;
    }
    if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)
        fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
```

Comment: But Can you tell me...why we use" ? " instead of "entry1" and "entry2".
I'm a bit confusing.

Comment: You want to check the database when the button is clicked, don't you?

Comment: yes...exactly...
if username and password is not in the database(which i have created) then it would not proceed to next window when button is clicked,otherwise it proceed.

Comment: This question (about fetching data) is answered. To ask about GTK event handlers, ask a new question.